# Cannot Navigate to Component Using lightning:isUrlAddressable

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm attempting to get a URL parameter into the context of a Lightning Component. I'm using the lightning:isUrlAddressable interface in the Lightning Component, however, when navigating to the URL for the Lightning Component, I'm presented with an error "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app."  Below is the error message, code for the Lightning Component, and the URL being used. What am I missing here?

[image: error]

AccountLookup.cmp

`<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable"
                access="global" >
    <lightning:card>
        Param1 = {!v.pageReference.state.extAccount}
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>`

URL I'm navigating to:
`https://<domain>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/AccountLookup?extAccount=XYZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With URLAddressable components, you must prefix both the component name as well as any URL parameters with "c__", it's silly, I know.

So your URL would be  `https://<domain>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__AccountLookup?c__extAccount=XYZ`

Comment: Thanks much, that worked! I'll add that the requirement of "c__" also extends to the pageReference class. So in the component I needed `Param1 = {!v.pageReference.state.c__extAccount}`

Comment: Where is this documented?